# How to add WooCommerce Add to Cart button in widget?

Tags: widgets, woocommerce-offtopic

How can I add a separate WooCommerce widget, with the Add to Cart button and its options, so I can display it anywhere in the sidebar of the product details page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Keyframe Woocommerce Widget
Description: Keyframe Woocommerce Add To Cart Sidebar Widget
Author: Keyframe
Version: 1.0
*/

// Block direct requests
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
die('-1');


add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
 register_widget( 'N_Widget' );
}); 

/**
* Adds N_Widget widget.
*/
class N_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'N_Widget', // Base ID
        __('N Widget', 'text_domain'), // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'N Sidebar Widget!', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
    }

    global $product;
    do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->product_type . '_add_to_cart'  );
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    }
    else {
        $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    }
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}

} // class N_Widget
```